# Can't edit a value in a table with triggers

Tags: mariadb, trigger, mariadb-10.4

So I'm trying to make a simple scheme of order-> payment-> shipping. Here is the structure of the main tables:

- cust_order (order_id, customer_id, catalog_id, items_ordered, order_date, payment_status(Paid/Unpaid), shipping_status (Preparing/Shipped))
- payment (payment_id, order_id, pay_bank, pay_accnum, pay_date)
- shipping (shipping_id, order_id, shipping_date)

And the plot is:

1. An order was made. The default value of payment_status would be Unpaid and shipping_status = Preparing
2. (Trigger 1) If an order was made, then a row will be inserted on payment table, with the value of pay_bank, pay_accnum, pay_date is NULL
3. Assume that the customer has paid, the value of pay_bank, pay_accnum, pay_date has been filled. Then (Trigger 2), the payment_status on the order table will be changed to 'Paid'
4. (Trigger 3) if the payment_status on the order table is changed to 'Paid', then a row will be inserted on shipping table  (so the shipping admin can see the order that need to be sent) with the shipping_date value is NULL
5. Assume that the shipping admin has send the product, he edited the value of shipping_date, so it's no longer NULL. Then (Trigger 4), the shipping_status in order table is changed to 'Shipped'

I've created all the 4 triggers. Here is the code:

**Trigger 1**

```
create trigger order_to_payment
-> after insert on cust_order
-> for each row
-> begin
-> insert into payment (order_id,catalog_id) 
-> values (new.order_id, new.catalog_id);
-> end;
-> //
```

**Trigger 2**

```
create trigger verifPay
-> after update on payment
-> for each row
-> begin
-> if new.pay_bank is NOT NULL and new.pay_accnum is NOT NULL and new.pay_date is NOT NULL then
-> update cust_order
-> set payment_status = 'Paid'
-> where order_id=new.order_id;
-> end if;
-> end;//
```

**Trigger 3**

```
create trigger paid_to_shipping
-> after update on cust_order
-> for each row 
-> begin
-> if new.payment_status = 'Paid' then
-> insert into shipping(order_id,customer_id)
-> values (new.order_id, new.customer_id);
-> end if;
-> end;
-> //
```

**Trigger 4**

```
create trigger ChangeShippedStatus
-> after update on shipping
-> for each row 
-> begin
-> if new.pay_date is NOT NULL then
-> update cust_order
-> set shipping_status='Shipped'
-> where order_id=new.order_id;
-> end if;
-> end;//
```

And here I found a trouble when I'm trying to edit the pay_date value on the shipping table, it says `#1442 - Can't update table 'shipping' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`

I've made a similar scheme before and it worked, so I'm trying to figure out where the problem is in this case

Comment: Please tag which database system and version.

Comment: it's 10.4.21-MariaDB

Comment: I'm not a fan of Triggers, especially not for putting business logic.  Suggest you write a Stored Procedure that encapsulates that flow.  (In doing so, you will probably discover the error in the Trigger.)